# Нужно сделать вывод по отдельности JS!! Пожалуйста

Tags: javascript, html

Первый калькулятор выводит сумму в два итога. Помогите пожалуйста сделать, чтобы по отдельности они работали, код почти готовый, чего-то не хватает. Пожалуйста, я буду очень благодарен за помощь!!

```js
let result = document.getElementById('result');
let result2 = document.getElementById('result2')
  
  function calc2(e) {

 
  let price = 0;
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input, select');
           
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i+=2) { 
      price += inputs[i].value * inputs[i+1].value;
    }
    e.innerHTML = price;  
  }
  
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input, select');
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].addEventListener('change',() => calc2(result));
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].addEventListener('change',() => calc2(result2));
    }
```

```html
<section id="calculator">   
        <div>
          <div >
            <label  for>1-я панель</label>
          </div>
          <span class="nn">
            <input type="number" value="0" name=""> 
            x
            <input type="number" value="0" name="">
            см
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div >
            <label for>2-я панель</label>
          </div>
          <span>
            <input type="number" value="0" name=""> 
            x
            <input type="number" value="0" name=""> 
            см  
          </span>
          <div>
           <span class="byn2" id="result">0</span></div>
        </div>
          
          
          <section id="calculator">   
        <div>
          <div >
            <label  for>1-я панель</label>
          </div>
          <span class="nn">
            <input type="number" value="0" name=""> 
            x
            <input type="number" value="0" name="">
            см
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div >
            <label for>2-я панель</label>
          </div>
          <span>
            <input type="number" value="0" name=""> 
            x
            <input type="number" value="0" name=""> 
            см  
          </span>
          <div>
           <span class="byn2" id="result2">0</span></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Третий аккаунт с этим калькулятором...... вам уже говорили что надо делать... сколько уже,  недели две прошло, можно было самому сделать........а я советовал с нуля сделать и поэтапно.....но вы чёт совсем не хотите сам делать.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я код исправил как мог и сделал в правильной форме, но не хватает чего-то чтобы выводы были разные

Comment: А аккаунты новые для чего создаете? я бы взял и обложился console.log() со всех сторон.

Comment: @SwaD а зачем console.log() со всех сторон?

Comment: @SwaD друг сказал что нужно как-то инпуты поделить и будет тогда разные выводы, но я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Да что бы отдебажить приклад. Понять, что куда передается и что не так идет. Что не соответствует ожиданиям. Спросите у друга, как решить данный кейс ))

Comment: @SwaD так я и говорю, знаю в чем проблема - разделить инпуты, но я честно не знаю что и как это делать, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @SwaD не надо пожалуйста советовать в качестве дебага вывод в консоль.....есть же отладчик.. ну право

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пожалуйста, мне уже просто нужно как-то добить это задание - код почти готовый, пару нюансов только решить, но я ихв упор не вижу

Comment: какая задача, конкретно? Какие еще 2 итога. Распишите нормально - что нужно?!!!

Comment: @Jackson спасибо большое за информативную работу!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
initCalculators();

function initCalculators() {
  const calculators = document.querySelectorAll('.calculator');
  calculators.forEach(calculator => initCalculator(calculator));
}

function initCalculator(calculatorSection) {
  const inputs = calculatorSection.querySelectorAll('input');
  const resultBlock = calculatorSection.querySelector('.result');
  
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('change', calculate);
  });
  
  function calculate() {
    let result = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i+=2) { 
      result += inputs[i].value * inputs[i+1].value;
    }

    resultBlock.innerHTML = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="calculator">   
  <div>
    <div >
      <label  for>1-я панель</label>
    </div>
    <span class="nn">
      <input type="number" value="0" name=""> 
      x
      <input type="number" value="0" name="">
      см
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div >
      <label for>2-я панель</label>
    </div>
    <span>
      <input type="number" value="0" name=""> 
      x
      <input type="number" value="0" name=""> 
      см  
    </span>
    <div>
      <span class="byn2 result" id="result">0</span></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="calculator">   
    <div>
      <div >
        <label  for>1-я панель</label>
      </div>
      <span class="nn">
        <input type="number" value="0" name=""> 
        x
        <input type="number" value="0" name="">
        см
      </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div >
        <label for>2-я панель</label>
      </div>
      <span>
        <input type="number" value="0" name=""> 
        x
        <input type="number" value="0" name=""> 
        см  
      </span>
      <div>
        <span class="byn2 result" id="result2">0</span></div>
    </div>
</section>
```